# Grouping a javascript array by time difference

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

## Example Input:

```
var Player = [
    {
        name: "John",
        Events: {
            timeList: ["7:00 AM", "9:00 AM", "12:01 PM", "2:00 PM"]
        },
        groups: {}
    },
    {
        name: "Doe",
        Events: {
            timeList: ["7:00 AM", "8:00 AM", "10:00 AM", "12:01 PM"]
        },
        groups: {}
    }
];
```

I am trying to loop through each player's timeList array and group every item in that array by a less than 2 Hour time difference between them.

I've tried looping through every element in the array and writing an if condition to see which elements match. However, I'm unable to push the grouped elements in separate arrays.

## Expected Output:

```
Player = [
    {
        name: "John",
        Events: {
            timeList: ["7:00 AM", "9:00 AM", "12:01 PM", "2:00 PM"]
        },
        groups: {0: ["7:00 AM", "9:00 AM"], 1: ["12:01 PM", "2:00 PM"]}
    },
    {
        name: "Doe",
        Events: {
            timeList: ["7:00 AM", "8:00 AM", "9:00 AM", "12:01 PM"]
        },
        groups: {0: ["7:00 AM", "8:00 AM", "9:00 AM"], 1: ["12:01 PM"]}
    }
];
```

The structure of the object can be changed if need be.

Thx a ton in advance.

Comment: Please post the code you have tried, and maybe a jsfiddle demo.

Comment: You will have to parse the times in some way. If the time strings all use the format in your question then it should be rather trivial. When you have parsed the strings it would just be a matter of looping over them and keeping track of the differences, and putting them in their respective buckets. Showing us what you have tried so far would allow us to give you feedback on it.

Comment: What would be the expected output if you had times like `7:00 AM`, `9:00 AM`, `11:00 AM`?

Comment: @user3771837 The example code you have shared give an idea that all of given time follow 12-Hour clock. So if given input is {{8:00    AM , 10:00 AM , 12:00 PM , 2:00PM }}, then the expected answer is {"0":[ 8:00 AM, 10:00 AM, 12:00 PM, 2:00 PM ]}..?? Also, almost same input  {{8:00    AM , 10:00 AM , 12:00 AM , 2:00PM }}, then by 12 hr clock logic & 2 or less hour difference, expected answer is {"0": [ 8:00 AM, 10:00 AM] , "1":[2:00 PM], "2": [12:00AM]}..? Right?

Comment: @RaeenHashemi: getting a fiddle ready. For now parsing the time into a 24 hour format and then calculating the time differences between them.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen: I've got the time converted into appropriate formats. There is ton of other logic which is why the fiddle is taking a bit. For now though, ive got the time sorted out but the part where i face a problem is in the logic while looping them.

Comment: @Rakesh_Kumar: if the given input is {{8:00 AM , 10:00 AM , 12:00 PM , 2:00PM }}..then the output should be {"0":[ 8:00 AM, 10:00 AM], "1": [12:00 PM, 2:00 PM ]}..I am basically trying to group a set of given times within a group of 2 hours ie all events within a 2 hour window to belong to the same group. The array can have n elements in it.

Comment: @PaulS. the expected output would be {0: [7:00 AM,9:00 AM, 11:00 AM]}..since each of those belong to a 2 hour or less window between them.

Comment: @user3771837 But the requirement says that if the difference is less or equal to 2 hrs, then make them in same group...which means [8:00 AM,10:00 AM, 12:00PM, 2:00 PM] should be in the same group as the difference between the timings is 2 hrs. Why the discrepancy?

Comment: @Rakesh_Kumar: I'm so sorry. In your given input, all of them would belong to the same group as each of them have a time difference of 2 hours. But if the time happened to be 12:01, it would then give the output i described. I'm sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @RaeenHashemi: trying to get the fiddle up but ive got ton of other logic in there. I've tried to boil down the problem to the simplest level possible. Hence, adding a fiddle with my existing code might be a little difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a function to standardise your times, write a function to compare a time to the previous time it was given (initial condition of `-Infinity`), loop over your *Arrays*.

```
function timeInMin(str) {
    str = str.split(/[: ]/);
    if (str[0] === '12') {
        if (str[2] === 'AM') {
            str[1] = 0;
        }
    } else if (str[2] === 'PM') {
        str[0] = (+str[0]) + 12;
    }
    return 60 * (+str[0]) + (+str[1]);
}

function groupFactory(groups) {
    var i = -1, last = -Infinity;
    groups = groups || {};
    return function addToGroup(time) {
        var mins = timeInMin(time);
        if (mins - last <= 2 * 60) {
            groups[i].push(time);
        } else {
            ++i;
            groups[i] = [time];
        }
        last = mins;
        return groups;
    };
}

var i, j, gf;
for (i = 0; i < Player.length; ++i) {
    gf = groupFactory(Player[i].groups);
    for (j = 0; j < Player[i].Events.timeList.length; ++j) {
        gf(Player[i].Events.timeList[j]);
    }
}
```

Results in

```
[
    {
        "name": "John",
        "Events": {
            "timeList": ["7:00 AM", "9:00 AM", "12:01 PM", "2:00 PM"]
        },
        "groups": {
            "0": ["7:00 AM", "9:00 AM"],
            "1": ["12:01 PM","2:00 PM"]
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Doe",
        "Events": {
            "timeList": ["7:00 AM", "8:00 AM", "10:00 AM", "12:01 PM"]
        },
        "groups": {
            "0": ["7:00 AM", "8:00 AM", "10:00 AM"],
            "1": ["12:01 PM"]
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Works great! could you please explain the logic you used in the groupFactory function? A little lost there.

Comment: `groupFactory` is a function to create another function. Things `var`d in `groupFactory` will be _"shared"_ across all invocations of the inner function. This means you can invoke the inner function, store data from the invocation, and let the second invocation give a result depending on the first invocation. A simple example of such a structure would be a counter that increments by `1` each invocation `function makeCounter() {var i = 0; return function () {return ++i;};}` then `counter = makeCounter(); counter(); counter(); counter();`. In `groupFactory` it's just a compare vs last then push